# How do you add something to an uninitialized variable? c#

Tags: c#

Im trying to make a cookie clicker style thing where every time you click something it adds 1 to a variable. Im trying to do `int clicks = clicks + 1` but it says that it is use of an uninitialized variable. I tried to set `int clicks = 0` but then it says that clicks is already defined in the scope. I tried to see if i could do something like `if (clicks == null)` but obviously it cant check it because it is not a variable. I have only used c# for like a day, can someone please help?

```
    private void cookie_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int clicks = 0;
        clicks = clicks + 1;
        numClicks.Text = "" + clicks;
    }
```

^ this is the code. i also realized when i click it, it resets itself to 0 and goes back to 1, so it cant go 1, 2, 3 etc. is there a way to set the variable when the form starts and then start to add on clicks? im so dumb

Comment: Don't use uninitialized variables to begin with. `int clicks = clicks + 1` makes no sense though. You can't increment something that doesn't even exist yet. `int clicks=0;` works. `clicks++` works. `clicks+=1` workds

Comment: Can we see your code? The code that declares `clicks`, in particular? Pro tip: always show the code you're asking about.

Comment: _I tried to set "int clicks = 0" but then it says that clicks is already defined in the scope_ You only use the `int` keyword when declaring the variable, do not use it afterwards.

Comment: _"is there a way to set the variable when the form starts and then start to add on clicks?"_ - yes. Make `clicks` a [class field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields) of your form. The code in question creates a _local_ (to the event handler's scope) variable. It won't be visible outside that block and it will not survive the control flow leaving the block. If you make it a class field, it will "persist" the value until the instance of that class is destroyed.

Answer (score 5):

```
int clicks = clicks + 1;
```

Is indeed nonsensical. This is the code that is declaring and initializing `clicks`, so it makes perfect sense that we can't ask "what is the value of `clicks`?" (in order so we can add one to it); until we have definitely assigned a value to `clicks`, the value is *undefined*.

Instead:

```
int clicks = 0;
```

And then when you want to increment it:

```
clicks++;
```

Comment: it works but i realized that this code runs when they clicks, so it sets clicks back to 0 and adds 1. ive been looking but i'm really confused, how can you declare clicks without having to declare it on the click event thing?

Comment: @oops you would declare it as a *field*, not a *local* - i.e. move the declaration *outside* of the method; however, you haven't told us what kind of UI this is : the previous would work for client apps like WPF, winforms, etc - but won't work for web, because of how the http life-cycle works

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to do something like this:

```
int clicks = 0;//Define an integer 'clicks' and set it to 0
//and in your click handler:
clicks = clicks + 1;//Increment your count.
```

Note:

- Clicks is an integer, it can never be null. (look up c# primitives for more info)
- Using int clicks = clicks + 1 doesn't make sense. At the right side of the equation, what's the value of clicks? It's not defined yet.

Comment: _"look up c# primitives"_ and/or [value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types).

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your implementation is that every time the function gets called the first thing it does is sets clicks to 0. You need to initialize it outside of the function to avoid this. If you initialize it in the class it will be set to 0 initially when the class is created then you can increase the value everytime the functions is called. Not sure exactly your use case but without more information I would recommend doing something like this.

```
class YourClass {
    // initialize outside of the function that increases the counter
    int clicks = 0;
    // rest of the code in class

    private void cookie_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clicks++;
        // this would also work: clicks = clicks + 1;
        numClicks.Text = "" + clicks;
    }
}
```